# Flutter crash on release start. E/LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory, Didn't find class "com.example.androidx. 17_4_2020

Tags: flutter, androidx

I have upgraded my flutter to latest version `1.18.0-6.0.pre.65 • channel master`
My app was working when released. but now, it is working in debug mode only.
and gives the error

```
E/LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.androidx" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example-w8uMhpPeS9WD7rhvuuQjbg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example-w8uMhpPeS9WD7rhvuuQjbg==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example-w8uMhpPeS9WD7rhvuuQjbg==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
```

I have tried mostly all available solutions like:

1:`invalidate cache,clean project,flutter clean,update,upgrade and rebuild`

2: `Add -keep class androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory { *; } to your proguard config so that this class won't be proguarded out`

3- `changed to stable channel` with no luck.
4- Created new flutter project and released it, gives the same error.

My gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-R'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
    buildToolsVersion = '30.0.0 rc2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!. 
for anyone will face this problem, the problem is some package you use.
try run release on real device and check log for the name of library name.so and downgrade its version from its change log